# URDF/COLLADA file is not a valid robot model | no name given for the robot | Universal Robots (UR)

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have dowloaded the Universal Robots (UR3, UR5 and UR10) from:

http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot

I am trying to load the Urdf | xacro file in Moveit setup assistant...However I cannot load the robot

The error msg in Movelt Apl is
"URDF/COLLADA file is not a valid robot model."

And the terminal returns me the following message:
"No name given for the robot"

I followed the "tutorial" given by the link above...I  executed  the commands:

rosdep update....rosdep install rosdistro etc... and source ...devel/bash..

I also dowloaded the package with the Abb robots....and there was no problem in load them in Moveit. However I need a robot with ee_effector to follow the tutorial from qbotics...Lenthin Joseph...form the book Mastering ROS... anyway when I was finishing the setup from Abb robot moveit stopped and a shadow color appeared..it stopped to work, I don't know why.
I would like to load the ur10 robot!

obs: I have already looked the answers similar to this issue in Forum, however they did not adressed my case!

Could someone help me to find the error?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327449/urdf/collada-file-is-not-a-valid-robot-model-%7C-no-name-given-for-the-robot-%7C-universal-robots-(ur)/) by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2019-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer you've posted is actually not *the* answer.

Those files are used by thousands of people and they are correct as-is.

The cause of your problem is that you've selected the wrong file to load.

Instead of loading `ur10e.urdf.xacro`, you should load the `ur10e_robot.urdf.xacro` file.

The former only defines the macro, but doesn't instantiate it. The latter is a top-level xacro that `include`s the appropriate files and then also instantiates the model.

Loading a file that only defines a macro will result in an empty file after the MSA tries to load it, hence the error.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3